# Reputation does not appear in achievements panel

Tags: bug, reputation, new-nav

I just noticed that the last reputation does not appear in the ACHIEVEMENTS panel:

[image]

You could see that I've just 15 in the picture when you could see that the real value is 70 as shown the picture below:

[image]

I am not sure if that is because of the new navbar or that is related to another issue.

Comment: Already a known issue, see the dupe.

Comment: True, doesn't noticed that.. thanks.